# sql not throwing invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am asking this question because I am not getting an error where I expect there should be an error.
Please help me understand under what circumstances this is possible. I have a query:

```
select foracid,acct_name, schm_code, schm_type from tbaadm.gam  where
acid  in(select acid from tbaadm.iar);
```

This query is returning results without throwing any error. I expect invalid identifier
because the table tbaadm.iar does NOT have a field acid.
When I run:

```
 select acid from tbaadm.iar;
```

I get:

```
ORA-00904: "ACID": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 772 Column: 8
```

I am using sqldeveloper and oracle 10g. It is kind of Strange to me. Worth to mention though is that there is a field in tbaadm.iar that is an id and so the right Query Should be:

```
select foracid,acct_name, schm_code, schm_type from tbaadm.gam  where
acid  in(select entity_id from tbaadm.iar);
```

What is going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A subquery that's used in an `IN` clause can reference columns from the outer query, because this is necessary in correlated subqueries. So your WHERE clause is equivalent to:

```
WHERE acid IN (SELECT tbaadm.gam.acid FROM tbaadm.iar)
```

An example of a correlated subquery that shows why this is necessary is:

```
SELECT *
FROM outer_table
WHERE somefield = (SELECT someotherfield 
                   FROM inner_table
                   WHERE inner_table.id = outer_table.inner_id)
```

This is the more common use, where the field from the outer table is used in a `WHERE` clause of the subquery. But SQL isn't picky about where the field from the outer query is used. It can be used anywhere in the subquery that an expression is permitted, which includes the `SELECT` clause.

Comment: Shouldn't the Subquery be valid? because `SELECT tbaadm.gam.acid FROM tbaadm.iar` will also not execute?

Comment: The subquery is valid because it's inside a query that selects from `tbaadbm.gam`.